# I can't use the Gtk.get-text instruction correctly in python

Tags: python, gtk

I'm writing a small program in Python with Gtk3 and this is part of the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class Layout(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Ricerca partite")
        self.set_default_size(265, 310)
        self.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
        layout = Gtk.Layout()
        self.add(layout)
        label = Gtk.Label("Inserisci i TAG della partita che cerchi")
        layout.put(label, 10, 10)

        xlabel = 10 ; ylabel = 50
        xentry = 90 ; yentry = 45
        yy=30

        label = Gtk.Label("    Event    ")
        layout.put(label, xlabel, ylabel)
        Event = Gtk.Entry()
        Event.set_text("---test---")
        layout.put(Event, xentry, yentry)
        ylabel += yy ; yentry += yy

        label = Gtk.Label("    Site    ")
        layout.put(label,xlabel, ylabel)
        Site = Gtk.Entry()
        layout.put(Site, xentry, yentry)
        ylabel += yy ; yentry += yy

        # ...
        # Other 5 labels and entries
        # ...

        button = Gtk.Button(label="  cerca  ")
        layout.put(button, 186, ylabel+10)
        button.connect("clicked", self.on_button_clicked)

        txt=Event.get_text() # I verify "Event" entry
        print(txt)

    def on_button_clicked(self, button):
        print("Button has been clicked!")
        txt=window.Event.get_text()
        print(ddd,type(ddd))

window = Layout()
window.show_all()

Gtk.main()
```

When the "Search" button is clicked I print "Button has been clicked"! and I would like to put in as many variables the content of the seven "entry" but, forgive my ignorance, despite all the trials, I can't get the result I want.

The error I receive is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scriptName.py", online 75, in on_button_clicked
    txt=window.Event.get_text ()
AttributeError:' Layout' object has no attribute' Event'.
```

Thank you and apologize for the bad English: translated with PC.

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to read up on [Python classes](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+class+tutorial) sometime. Anyway, you were accessing a new class from inside the first class, leading to your error. Here is the proper code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class Layout(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Ricerca partite")
        self.set_default_size(265, 310)
        self.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
        layout = Gtk.Layout()
        self.add(layout)
        label = Gtk.Label("Inserisci i TAG della partita che cerchi")
        layout.put(label, 10, 10)

        xlabel = 10 ; ylabel = 50
        xentry = 90 ; yentry = 45
        yy=30

        label = Gtk.Label("    Event    ")
        layout.put(label, xlabel, ylabel)
        self.Event = Gtk.Entry()
        self.Event.set_text("---test---")
        layout.put(self.Event, xentry, yentry)
        ylabel += yy ; yentry += yy

        label = Gtk.Label("    Site    ")
        layout.put(label,xlabel, ylabel)
        Site = Gtk.Entry()
        layout.put(Site, xentry, yentry)
        ylabel += yy ; yentry += yy

        # ...
        # Other 5 labels and entries
        # ...

        button = Gtk.Button(label="  cerca  ")
        layout.put(button, 186, ylabel+10)
        button.connect("clicked", self.on_button_clicked)

        txt=self.Event.get_text() # I verify "Event" entry
        print(txt)

    def on_button_clicked(self, button):
        print("Button has been clicked!")
        text=self.Event.get_text()
        print(text,type(text))

window = Layout()
window.show_all()

Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you very much and sorry for my ignorance!!!

Comment: @Ave: never be sorry of not knowing something, as nobody knows everything ;).